# Pass semicolon in Ant as a parameter

Tags: java, ant, escaping

I want to pass ";;;" string as a string parameter in my Ant task:

```
<mytask param=";;;"/>
```

but Ant consider semicolon as a special symbol and raises an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference`

how can I escape ; symbol to pass it to Ant?

p.s. also I found that I can't pass { symbol,
so I wonder what's the common way to escape characters in Ant?
I've tried "$;$;$;" but it's not working for me

UPDATE: 
sample code:

```
public class MyTask extends Task {
    private String value;
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

and ant task:

```
<taskdef name="mytask" classpath="build/lib/CustomTasks.jar"
   classname="MyTask"/>
<mytask value=";;;"/>
```

Comment: Can you post a small working sample which depicts your problem?

Comment: @tsds Your sample works for me. I've just compiled your code and test mytask target - it works well for ";;;" and "{" values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not any problem with this sample:

```
<target name="test_passing_params">
    <antcall target="test_echo">
        <param name="param1" value=";;;"/>
        <param name="param2" value="{"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
<target name="test_echo">
    <echo>param1: ${param1}</echo>
    <echo>param2: ${param2}</echo>
</target>
```

Output:

> echo 
>   param1: ;;; 
>   echo 
>   param2: {

May be problem in implementation of `mytask` task?

Comment: you're right the problem was inside my java class - I used String.replaceAll with replacement containing & symbol, thank you for ensuring me in correctness of ant task code

Answer (score 0):

to escape semicolon use: `&#59;`

Refer to for complete list at:
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_ascii.asp

Answer (score 0):

**One note on passing special characters to ant in general:**

I used to pass a password to ant SQL task but it failed on special characters such as **@$#%^&*!**

Switching **&** with **&\amp;** worked, but the other characters such as **$** or **#** failed.

I ended up with replacing the password variable string directly inside the ant build file (using any search-replace script such as Linux's sed), rather than sending the parameter to the script using -D.

So if possible, don't waste your time on escaping or switching any special character you find - try to use an easier search-replace solution.