# parsing ";" separated XML value with Ant script

Tags: java, xml, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass semicolon in Ant as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804567/pass-semicolon-in-ant-as-a-parameter)

I have to read this `XE` from this xml attribute tag

```
<databases key="Test" type=".configdb">
      <dbname>test</dbname>
      <driver type=".dbdriver">
        <attributes>localhost;1521;XE;false</attributes>
        <driverType>Oracle thin</driverType>
      </driver>
      <password>965449DE3DB045FE</password>
      <user>test</user>
    </databases>
```

with Ant script.

Having seen lot of ideas; but seems all long paths and not even takes to exact destination.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have this tag in some `resource.xml` . You can parse `XE` with Ant's javascript engine by using a [scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) snippet.
**build.xml** :

```
<target name="something" ...
...
  <scriptdef language="javascript" name="split">
    <attribute name="input"/>
    <attribute name="output"/>
    values = attributes.get("input");
    project.setProperty(attributes.get("output"), values.split(";")[2]);
  </scriptdef>

  <xmlproperty file="resource.xml"/>
  <echo message="Original: ${databases.driver.attributes}"/>
  <split input="${databases.driver.attributes}" output="result" />
  <echo message="Split: ${result}"/>
...
</target>
```

When running this task you'll get:

```
something:
[xmlproperty] Loading /home/code/resource.xml
     [echo] Original: localhost;1521;XE;false
     [echo] Split: XE
```